# How do i make this a category list instead of a drop down

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to take the this current code `<%= search_form.collection_select :tag_id, @tags, :id, :name %>` and want to have it list vertically the tags i have. Right now it list them in a drop down menu. I am very new to ruby and rail so I am also open to any suggestion to ebooks or tutorials anyone recommends. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  <li><%= tag.name %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: ok yes this is what i wanted, but i its just listing them without making them a clickable link.

Comment: @BluGeni Don't you know `HTML` ? Just add a `<a>` around the `tag.name`.

Comment: @oldergod yes i do but when i add <a><%= tag.name %></a> it gives the appearance you can click it (underlines the tag) but still has no action like it did in the drop down.

Comment: you need to set the `href` attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
<ul>
<%= @tags.map { |tag| content_tag(:li, tag.name) }.join
</ul>
```

Or:

```
<ul>
<% @tags.each { |tag| concat(content_tag(:li, tag.name)) }
</ul>
```